# Javascript: Sort array based on subarray element contain string date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array `complexArray` that I want to sort by the first value of its subarray (String). Sorting works as desired in the `simpleArray`. For the complex array in use a custom sorting function which works fine with Int values (e.g. at position [1]) but not for the String at position [0].

How do I need to adapt the custom sorting function to make this work?

```js
var simpleArray = ["2018-12-06T19:48:39Z","2018-12-15T19:48:39Z","2018-12-13T16:37:04Z"];
simpleArray.sort();
console.log(simpleArray);

var complexArray = [["2018-12-06T19:48:39Z", 1, "15m 10s"],["2018-12-15T19:48:39Z", 3, "16m 25s"],["2018-12-13T16:37:04Z", 2,"21m 41s"]];   
complexArray.sort(function(a, b){
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
console.log(complexArray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert date strings to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and then compare them in sort function.

```js
var complexArray = [["2018-12-06T19:48:39Z", 1, "15m 10s"],["2018-12-15T19:48:39Z", 3, "16m 25s"],["2018-12-13T16:37:04Z", 2,"21m 41s"]]
  
complexArray.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]);
});

console.log(complexArray);
```